# Prove that if $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then 5 divides abc. a,b,c are positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

My question is about proving that if $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2,$$ then 5 divides abc. a,b,c are positive integers.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: My question is what have you tried.  It should be an easy problem in modular arithmetic.

Comment: Can you express a,b,c using just 2 variables p,q under given conditions?

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/pythTripleDiv.shtml

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to check whether $5$ divides at least one of $a,b,c$, since then it will divide the product. If $5$ divides $a$ or $b$ you are done, so the question is whether two squares not divisible by $5$ can sum to another square also not divisible by $5$.

If you know modular arithmetic, this should be easy. Check the possible values of squares of $a$ and $b$ when they are not divisible by $5$.

If you do not know modular arithmetic, it is still possible to use an informal version of it by seeing that the square numbers end in the digits $0,1,4,9,6,$ or $5$. Drawing the final digits of $a^2$ and $b^2$ from the pool of $1,4,9,6$, you can try adding these possibilities together to see that what viable combinations that might be squares.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$$a^2+b^2=c^2\iff a=2st,\space b=s^2-t^2,\space c=s^2+t^2$$ In $\mathbb F_5$ one has
$$s=1\Rightarrow abc=2t(1-t^4)=0\text{ because } 1-t^4=0\text{ for all } t\ne 0$$
Similarly with $s=2,3,4$